# Convert css system colors to hex with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to get the hex or rgb values of the color names for these colors?

http://artific.com/library/css-2-system-colors.html

Say for example that I set a div to use "windowFrame" as the background color.  Could I use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle somehow?

Comment: good question but possible duplicate of [Color code from color name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321995/color-code-from-color-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getComputedStyle seems to work.

Firebug Output (working on http://artific.com/library/css-2-system-colors.html) :

```
var t = document.getElementsByClassName("window")[0]; window.getComputedStyle(t).backgroundColor;
"rgb(255, 255, 255)"

>>> var t = document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0]; window.getComputedStyle(t).backgroundColor;
"rgb(240, 240, 240)"

>>> var t = document.getElementsByClassName("info")[0]; window.getComputedStyle(t).backgroundColor;
"rgb(225, 225, 225)"
```